# When I running eclipse I get 2 errors

Tags: eclipse, adt, eclipse-adt, android-sdk-2.3

When I running eclipse I get 2 errors.

Android SDK Content Loader

> parseSdkContent failed java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: MD5
>   MessageDigest not available

Indexing help

> An internal error occurred during: "Indexing help...".
>   java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

How I fix it?

Comment: This happens when you start Eclipse?

Comment: yes. its happens when I start Eclipse